# DRY method for ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, dry

I have a number of shared DSL code in ActiveAdmin; I have looked into a number of ways to share the code, some of which included creating a module that I include in the resource and others that included, adding the path to the Active Admin initializers.

However, I've found that nothing is working. I think there should be a simple way to just share similar code across the resources -- and by code it is really DSL including Arbre and other domain specific language.

Here are the kinds of things I hope to share across the board:

```
 index do
   selectable_column
   id_column
   column :email
   column :current_sign_in_at
   column :sign_in_count
   column :created_at
   actions
 end


 filter :email
 filter :current_sign_in_at
 filter :sign_in_count
 filter :created_at


 menu false

 scope :active
 scope :inactive
 scope :all_items, :default => true

  member_action :toggle_activate, method: :get do 
  ...
  end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I definitely want to be a DRY coder.

Answer (score 1):

How about including the following mixin to your classes:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      # your shared code here
    end
  end
end
```